# How to iterate through two dataframes to find the closest value on second dataframe without looping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function that iterates through 3 dataframes and creates 20 new columns based on the closest values found on second and third dataframes and the tables have about 20000 rows. I have gotten the code to work with a primitive loop but I am aware that this is the most inefficient way of doing this. However, I haven't been able to figure out the way of doing this the Pandas way (Do i need to use "assign"?).

How can I get the following (simplified) code to be as fast as possible and eliminate the loop? It is taking over 10 minutes when the tables are over 10000 rows and I need to find values from 20 different columns.

```
import pandas as pd


def find_closest_size():
    df = pd.DataFrame(data={'datetime': ["2019-10-03T08:23:30-06:00", "2019-10-03T08:23:35-06:00", 
                                         "2019-10-03T08:24:04-06:00", "2019-10-03T08:24:33-06:00", 
                                         "2019-10-03T08:29:23-06:00", "2019-10-03T09:06:20-06:00", 
                                         "2019-10-03T09:10:24-06:00", "2019-10-03T09:18:40-06:00", 
                                         "2019-10-03T09:19:04-06:00", ]})
    df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
    df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].dt.tz_localize(None)

    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'datetime': ["10/2/2019 0:00", "10/3/2019 0:00", "10/3/2019 2:30", 
                                          "10/4/2019 0:00", "10/5/2019 0:00"], 
                             'size': [12.25, 12.25, 12.25, 12.25, 12.25]})

    df2['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['datetime'])

    i = df['datetime'].index[0]
    while i <= df['datetime'].index[-1]:
        df.loc[i, 'Hole Size'] = round(float(df2[df2['datetime'] == min(df2['datetime'], key=lambda 
                                       x: abs(x - df.loc[i, 'datetime']))]['size'].tolist()[0]), 3)
        i += 1

    print(df)


find_closest_size()
```

Comment: Search for `pd.merge_asof`?

Comment: This is the function I've needed. Thank you!